# Is there a method to prove that data has been fetched from a block on a blockchain?

Tags: calldata, chaindata, proof

I'm considering a problem that I havent seen someone else look at yet. The problem statement is how can we prove that some data (e.g., a transaction, a block header) has been fetched from a block of a blockchain? To provide an example, suppose I fetch the block header of a block in Ethereum. Is there a way to prove to a third party that the data that I have fetched is actually a block header of Ethereum without them having to check it themselves on Ethereum? I'm thinking of some sort of zk-proof or a "Proof of Fetched Data". I havent seen this anywhere but maybe someone has seen something along these lines.

Comment: People have been looking this problem since blockchains have been invented, roughly more than a decade now.

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the context.

A block header contains various information. Proving that all of that is plausible in a given block requires that the previous block hash is also correct. So you need to be able to prove that the data you give is valid data in a certain context. The same goes for a block.

If you need to prove that the block (or its header) is an actual block in the blockchain, you can use *storage proofs*. Storage proofs are a way of proving that certain data was part of the blockchain at a certain block. The verifier has to have some context against which to verify the proof - the exact required data depends on the type of storage proof. Merkle proofs are one option, or using light clients is another.

You can read more about storage proofs for example [here](https://www.starknet.io/en/posts/developers/what-are-storage-proofs-and-how-can-they-improve-oracles).

The concept and implementation of storage proofs is far from trivial, but is conceptually solid. The concept is viable way to, for example, prove for chain A that you burned an NFT in chain B.

Comment: To expand this answer, the solutions to prove something happening in a blockchain are based on [light clients](https://ethereum.org/en/developers/docs/nodes-and-clients/light-clients/). For example, bridge technology like NEAR <-> Ethereum rainbow bridge has its light client. Light client is responsible for managing the minimum state you need to verify something has happened on a block chain (block headers, numbers. etc.)

Comment: Hmm, thanks. This prompted me to read a bit more on the topic. Edited answer to add info about merkle proofs and light clients - there are various ways on how storage proofs can be utilized.

Answer (score 2):

If the requirement is *without checking the Blockchain*, the short answer is no.

When you say, *to prove that data has been fetched from X*, it means *the information exists on X*. And the Blockchain is the tool you can use to prove the existence of an off-chain piece of information, using any kind of proofs, not the contrary.

For example, you can say that a transaction is in the Blockchain with just the TX and a receipt. Because you can compute the tx's hash, you can compute the root of the Merkle-tree with the receipt, and if the root hash is stored in the Blockchain then your transaction is included.

You must check the actual presence of the root hash in the Blockchain to ensure the entire concept works.

Even if you involve ZK techs, you are out of luck.

Those techniques allow you to prove the execution of a function or a computation, not the existence of something **inside a specific system**.  So while you can technically prove with a computation that a piece of information still exists **somewhere** (i.e., a proof of storage), you cannot prove that information exists exactly **there** (i.e., on Ethereum, Bitcoin, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are describing a Merkle Tree. A Merkle Tree (singular version Merkle Proof) is a way of cryptographically proving that a piece (pieces) of data stored off chain is accurate and untampered with. An example implementation would be OpenZeppelin's MerkleProof library:

https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-contracts/blob/master/contracts/utils/cryptography/MerkleProof.sol

As a related note, a *blockhash* is the unique identifier of a block on Ethereum. Every block has a different blockhash. You can check the blockhash of a particular block `block.blockhash` and then hash all your data with that value. If you want to go further, make sure that hash resolves to a magic predefined `bytes4` value that you set in your contract.

This is pretty much how implementations like `ERC721` know that another contract can receive and handle `ERC721` tokens properly.

If third parties know that you are doing this, they can relatively easily decode that data using that blockhash and, optionally, check that the decoded hash ID of all of your transactions resolves to your magic value. In this way they will know arbitrarily that your data is taken from the Ethereum blockchain.